# The product of Lindelöf spaces

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $X= \prod_{n\in \omega} X_n\subset \prod_{n\in \omega}\aleph_n$, where $X_n \subset \aleph_n$ (where $\aleph_n$ is the space with order topology) is Lindelöf for each $n\in \omega$. My question is this:

> Must $X$ be Lindelöf?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Which topology does each $\aleph_n$ have? If it's the order topology, then your claim that each $X_n$ must be countable is wrong. If it's the discrete topology then the answer to your question is easily yes, because $X$ would then be homeomorphic to the irrational numbers.

Comment: Yes, $X_n$ may not be countable, it only has countable cofinality.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that the product of countably many copies of $\omega$ is Lindelof?

Comment: "Countable cofinality" does not tell the whole story. For a set of ordinals to be Lindelöf, it is necessary that the set contain all its limit points of uncountable cofinality. But that is not sufficient, since if it omits uncountably many limit points (of countable cofinality) on a scattered set, then we can also make a violation of the Lindelöf property.

Comment: Is it true that a set of ordinals is Lindelöf in the order topology if and only if it contains all its limit points, except for countably many points of countable cofinality?

Comment: Isn't it the case that if $X$ consists of all isolated points of $\omega_1 + 1$ along with the last point, then $X$ is Lindel\"{o}f?

Comment: Lemme give a guess, first it looks like that being Lindelof is a property which is equivalent to being a stationary set which reflected at every point of uncoutable cofinality. The product topology is equvalent to the topology generated by triangles which allows you to make an alignment via Godel function. But the Godel function is closed. Therefore I think is possible to show that X is Lindelof.